# Every time I do Node which usually works it gives me an error it stars by loading normally and then it gives me an error

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
D:\MovedFilesRZHDTP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:237
    if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');
                                                   ^

Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (D:\MovedFilesRZHDTP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:237:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\MovedFilesRZHDTP\Desktop\DiscordBot\Bot.js:90:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my code is like that, it wouldn't let me post it for some reason.

Comment: Sounds like your Discord token is invalid... :)

Comment: It says that it is invalid so it tried putting in a new token but it still wouldn't work

Comment: Can you share some of your code related to this error?

Answer (score 1):

Search for `client.login` or anything like that with the login function. And then paste in your bot token as a string in its parameter.
Next time on stack overflow, never forget to share codes otherwise it would be hard to help you (remove any tokens from the code ofc)